# Excel 2010 Macro to create new sheet, and rename

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

So i'm looking to take the sheet "New" and use it as a template. I'm often creating new sheets, and it would be nice to automate it a bit. So far i've created a Macro to Unhide the template sheet, create copy, hide original, and rename new sheet. The problem i'm having is that when i recorded the macro, i copied Cell A2 from the Home sheet and pasted it into the new sheet name. It didn't pick up the paste, rather then just the name that was pasted. Is there a way for it to paste the contents of Cell A2 into the new sheet name?

Macro code i have thus far.

```
Sub CreateNewSheet()
'
' CreateNewSheet Macro
'

'
Sheets("New").Visible = True
Sheets("New").Select
Sheets("New").Copy Before:=Sheets(1)
Sheets("New").Select
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Visible = False
Sheets("Home").Select
Range("A2").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("New (2)").Select
Sheets("New (2)").Name = "Raptor"
End Sub
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
And if i happen to figure this out, i'll post the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub CreateNewSheet()
'
' CreateNewSheet Macro
'

'
Sheets("New").Visible = True
Sheets("New").Select
Sheets("New").Copy Before:=Sheets(1)
Sheets("New").Select
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Visible = False
Sheets("New (2)").Select
Sheets("New (2)").Name = Sheets("Home").Range("A2").Value
End Sub
```